# XMS.NET exits the process on factory.CreateConnection

Tags: c#, .net, jms, ibm-mq, xms

This is a follow up on [XMS.NET hanging indefinitely on factory.CreateConnection("username", null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044783/xms-net-hanging-indefinitely-on-factory-createconnection) .

As recommended in the comments, I installed the newest versions of MQ client and XMS.NET.
The application stopped hanging, now it just terminates the process after a few seconds. There is no exception beingh thrown.
The only information provided is the output I got when I turned full XMS logging.

This happens on the call to `factory.CreateConnection`

This is the tail of the output:

```
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:389693 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 > UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ method=NmqiConnect(String,NmqiConnectOptions,MQConnectOptions,Hconn,Phconn,out int,out int) [:] org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
entry [SV2098743] [IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiConnectOptions] [IBM.WMQ.MQConnectOptions#00B8956A] [] [<null>] [pCompCode : out] [pReason : out]
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:396694 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 > UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ method=GetUnmanagedHconn(Hconn) [:] org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
entry []
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:400694 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 > UOW= source= method=GetUnmanagedHconn(NmqiEnvironment,Object,Hconn) [:] org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
entry
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:404695 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source= org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
Hconn Value:0
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:406695 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 < UOW= source= method=GetUnmanagedHconn(NmqiEnvironment,Object,Hconn) rc=OK [:] org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
exit
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:407695 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 < UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ method=GetUnmanagedHconn(Hconn) rc=OK [:] org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
exit
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:423697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
Object ID      : 'IBM.WMQ.MQConnectOptions#00B8956A'
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:425697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
version        : 5 (hex 5)
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:427697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
options        : 64 (hex 40)
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:429697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
clientConnOffset: 0 (hex 0)
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:430697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
clientConnPtr  : [490028864]
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:431697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
connTag        : 0
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:432697 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
_SSLConfigPtr  : [0]
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:433698 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
_SSLConfigOffset: 0 (hex 0)
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:434698 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
connectionId   : 0
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:435698 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
securityParmsOffset: 0 (hex 0)
[26.06.2015 10:07:03:437698 W. Europe Standard Time] 00000009 d UOW= source=IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiStructureFormatter org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Message Service Client for .NET thread=[1 : 0]
securityParmsPtr: [490004432]
The program '[8740] WebServiceTesting.vshost.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. What version of MQ client you installed, v7.1 or 7.5 or 8.0 MQ? I am assuming you installed MQ v8 Client. From version v7.1, XMS .NET comes bundled with MQ Client. So when you install MQ Client, XMS .NET also gets installed. Hence there is no need for separately installing IA9H (XMS .NET) client again. So please uninstall IA9H and try again.

I would have expected a warning while installing IA9H when MQ Client was already installed. Apologies, I should have mentioned about this in your another question.

Comment: I uninstalled the software and after that installed just the v8 MQ Client alone.
I referenced the C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\IBM.XMS.dll library from my .NET application.

Now I am getting an {"Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.XMS.Client.Impl, Version=8.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"IBM.XMS.Client.Impl, Version=8.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b"}.

Comment: I reinstalled the software again, manually adjusted the PATH variabe. First, the app just terminated itself on the .Connect call. Then I switched the client from UNMANAGED back to regular CLIENT, and now I am at least getting something:     CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2009.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.
See the linked exception for more information.

Comment: When switching to UNMANAGED, the automatic process exit occurs again... :(

Comment: I think your MQ client installation has got messed up. Suggest you to uninstall all. Ensure there are no traces of XMS in Windows Global Assembly Cache (GAC). GAC will be under Windows\Assebly directory. If problem still persists raise a PMR.

Comment: I ran the ResetMQ.cmd file after the uninstall and before the new install. The issue still exists. I also checked C:\Windows\assembly and the XMS files are there with a 8.0.0.3 version, which should be the newest one, correct?

Comment: Yes, 8.0.0.3 is latest.

Comment: We need further to diagnose this further. Can you please raise PMR? or you can also reach me on my IBM email id registered in my profile.

Comment: Hi Shashi.
Thanks for your help. I am now reaching the owners of the queue (the server side) to put together the relevant information - maybe they will have something in their logs. I can imagine than just the information of "exiting the process" or the logs from my client will not be sufficient for you, or would they?

Comment: You can do another thing: Open a command prompt and navigate to <mq install>\bin directory. Then run 'amqiregisterdotnet.cmd /u' command. This will unregister all MQ/XMS .NET assemblies from GAC. Go to GAC and see if there any other XMS .NET assemblies. If any, manually remove them using gacutil command. After cleaning up GAC of XMS .NET assemblies, run amqiregisterdotnet.cmd command again (don't use /u option). This will register XMS assemblies. Now run your application.

Comment: Thanks shashi. I have unregistered everything from GAC and registered it again. But still, un the unmanaged mode, the process is just terminated on the call to factory.CreateConnection